# Need help count inversions with merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

The following code counts inversions in an array `nums` (pairs `i,j` such that `j>i && nums[i] > nums[j]`) by merge sort.

Is it possible to use the same approach to count the number of special inversions like `j>i && nums[i] > 2*nums[j]`?

How should I modify this code?

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    int[] nums = {9, 16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println("Strong Inversions: " + countInv(nums));         
}

public static int countInv(int nums[])
{  
    int mid = nums.length/2;
    int countL, countR, countMerge;

    if(nums.length <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int left[] = new int[mid];
    int right[] = new int[nums.length - mid];

    for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        left[i] = nums[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length - mid; i++)
    {
        right[i] = nums[mid+i];
    }

    countL = countInv (left);
    countR = countInv (right);

    int mergedResult[] = new int[nums.length];
    countMerge = mergeCount (left, right, mergedResult);

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = mergedResult[i];
    }

    return (countL + countR + countMerge);
}


public static int mergeCount (int left[], int right[], int merged[])
{
    int a = 0, b = 0, counter = 0, index=0;

    while ( ( a < left.length) && (b < right.length) )
    {
        if(left[a] <= right[b])
        {
            merged [index] = left[a++];
        }
        else 
        {   
            merged [index] = right[b++];
            counter += left.length - a;
        }
        index++;
    }

    if(a == left.length)
    {
        for (int i = b; i < right.length; i++)
        {
            merged [index++] = right[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = a; i < left.length; i++)
        {
            merged [index++] = left[i];
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I tried this

```
while ((a < left.length) && (b < right.length)) {
    if (left[a] <= right[b]) {
        merged[index] = left[a++];
    } else {
        if (left[a] > 2 * right[b]) {
            counter += left.length - a;
        }
        merged[index] = right[b++];
    }
    index++;
}
```

but there's a bug in the while loop, when `left[a]<2*right[b]` but `left[a+n] maybe>2*right[b]`, for instance left array is `{9,16}` and right array is `{5,6}`, *9<2*5* but *16>2*5*. My code just skip cases like this and the result number is less than it should be

Comment: Btw, don't copy arrays. All your work can be done in `nums`. I bet that if you avoid creating and coping arrays at each recursive call, you will gain a lot of time. In fact, it is more or less equivalent to do the merge before making the recursive call (moreover, your function will be tail recursive).

Comment: Oh, and if you still want to keep copying arrays, you can use `System.arraycopy` (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)). For example, to initialise left: `System.arraycopy(nums, 0, left, 0, mid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while` loop in `mergeCount` serves two functions: merge `left` and `right` into `merged`, and count the number of `left`–`right` inversions. For special inversions, the easiest thing would be to split the loop into two, counting the inversions first and then merging. The new trigger for counting inversions would be `left[a] > 2*right[b]`.

The reason for having two loops is that counting special inversions needs to merge `left` with `2*right`, and sorting needs to merge `left` with `right`. It might be possible to use three different indexes in a single loop, but the logic would be more complicated.

Comment: Yeah I did try to put that trigger in the while loop,

Comment: @Ryan Did you split the loop and leave the merge condition alone? It won't work otherwise.

Comment: I've edited my question and I don't know if that's what you were trying to say. I'm new to this please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while ( ( a < left.length) && (b < right.length) ) {
        if(left[a] <= right[b]) {
            merged [index] = left[a++];
        } else {
            counter += updateCounter(right[b],a,left);
            merged [index] = right[b++];
        }
        index++;
        //Rest of the while loop
    }
    //Rest of the mergeCount function
}

public static int updateCounter(int toSwitch, int index, int[] array) {
    while(index < array.length) {
        if(array[index] >= 2*toSwitch)
            break;
        index++;
    }
    return array.length-index;
}
```

Not very efficient, but it should do the work. You initialise `index` with `a`, because elements lower than `a` will never will never meet the condition.

Comment: Merging and counting "inversions" will not work in a single loop any more.

Comment: Yes indeed. Sorry. I will edit my post with a working solution asap.